# A blank grid with a random green place in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gridview, random, matlab-figure

I created a 100x100 lattice using this code :

```
L=ones(101,1)*(1:101);
for i=2:101
    for j=1:101
        L(i,j)=10*(i-1)+j;
    end
end
M=L;
x=randi([1 100]);
y=randi([1 100]);
M(x,y)=0;
```

I want to generate a blank 100x100 grid with the case containing "0"
 in green.

Note: I tried this method but it doesn't work

```
map1 = [1 1 1]; 
colormap(map1);
pcolor(L)

map2 = [0 1 0];
colormap(map2);
pcolor(M(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code is good. you just need to change the last part

```
map2 = ones(max(M(:)),3);
map2(1,:) = [0 1 0];
colormap(map2);
pcolor(M);
```

you need to get the a colormap that represents all of the possible colros in your map. si thats what the first line does, it sets all colors to be white. the next line changes the first element (wich will correspond to 0) to be green

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this is the final answer

```
L=ones(101,1)*(1:101);
L(1,1)=2;
for i=2:101
    for j=1:101
        L(i,j)=10*(i-1)+j;
    end
end

M=L;
x=randi([1 100]);
y=randi([1 100]);
M(x,y)=0;


map2 = ones(max(M(:)),3);
map2(1,:) = [0 1 0];
image(M);
```